# How can I cache my dynamic iPhone webapp for working offline?

Tags: php, iphone, web-applications, offline, iphone-web-app

I am having an iPhone web app written in PHP and using the WebApp.Net framework. I would like to make this application work offline as well. As I understood I can not use the manifest tag of HTML5 because my files are PHP and not html. Or at least it didn't work with it and I don't know if I am in the right direction.

Does anyone have any idea for how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the role of PHP in your app? Are you using it to connect to a DB, generate content, etc?

Comment: Hi, I am using it for generating content basically.

Answer (score 1):

You can cache any static file, no matter how it is generated. You must cache via manifest all your html, javascript and css (and graphics also, if they are small). Use LocalStorage to store JSON requests needed in offline mode. Use online mode to synchronize data you work on into LocalStorage.

You haven't stated what is your application for and what should be done in offline mode, but generally the only way I see as for now is to fully AJAXise all functionality that will work in offline.

You can browse StackOverflow for tags [html5+javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5+javascript) for general discrussions, or [html+javascript+mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5+javascript+mobile) for more specific.

Comment: Please explain how you can cache an MP3 file for offline use.